# how to add specific information to json test report using pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I want to add extra information in my test report using pytest.
As an example I want to add steps in my test cases.
If I use tests that does not inherit from unittest.TestCase every thing works as expected.
Example say I have a  test script  test_script.py:

```
def test_01(json_metadata):
   # Step A
   json_metadata["step_1"]= { 
   "status": "passed",
   "message": "blabla"
   }
   assert not False
```

In the generated report I got the needed information:

```
{
....
    "tests": [
        {
            .....
            ,
            "metadata": {
                "step_1": {
                    "status": "passed",
                    "message": "balbla"
                }
.....
}
```

the command used to execute tests and to generate the report:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from os import environ
   
    cmd = ["-vs", "./test-scriptf.py", 
        "--log-cli-level=debug", 
        "--json-report", 
        "--json-report-file=test-report.json",
        "--json-report-indent=4",
        ]
    retCode = pytest.main(cmd, plugins=[MyPlugin()])
```

The Class MyPlugin defines a hook to add the start and end of test execution:

```
import pytest
import sys

class MyPlugin:

    @pytest.hookimpl(optionalhook=True)
    def pytest_json_runtest_metadata(self, item, call):
        if call.when != 'call':
            return {}
        return {'start_execution': call.start, 'end_execution': call.stop}
```

The problem is if I want to use same logic but for tests that inherits from unittest.TestCase (it is a legacy code and I want to keep old code and adding minimum change)

Example of test case:

```
class TestMock(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tc_start_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.listAlpha=["A", "B", "C"]
        
        print("Test Setup")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("Test Tear Down")
    
    @pytest.mark.ts01
    def test_001(self):
        """mock test 01
        """
        #add extrat information to json_metadata
        self.assertIn("A", self.listAlpha, "List should contain A")
```

I'm using those packages: pytest, pytest-json-report
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I found my self a  solution. It consists to get rid of python unittest framework and use pytest. So the class looks like: ```class TestMock():
    def setup_method(self):
        self.tc_start_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.listAlpha=["A", "B", "C"]
        print("Test Setup")
    def teardown_method(self,  json_metadata):
        print("Test Tear Down")
    @pytest.mark.ts01
    def test_001(self):
        """mock test 01
        """
        json_metada["step_1"]="blabla"
        assert "A" in self.listAlpha, "List should contain A"```